# How do I find the necessary arc length if I want a certain height for an arch in building?

Tags: trigonometry, applications

I am trying to build a hoop house/greenhouse.  I will need to bend my poles so that there is enough height but still wide enough at the ground.  I cannot figure out how to calculate it.

If I have a 14' wide base, that's the diameter of the circle, radius 7.  I also thought the 7 here was a chord for the formulas.

I tried [this](https://www.mathopenref.com/sagitta.html) formula, `Sagitta = 7 - sqrt(7^2-7^2)`.  This gives me 7.  But I don't know how that helps me because I need a piece of PVC that will give me that Sagitta height, and I do not "see," and maybe this is where I am wrong, that a 14' piece of PVC will bend enough to give me 7' high, if the ground is 14'.

What am I doing wrong (or right)?  I thought this would give me the length of the arc necessary and I'm not real sure of the angle I would bend it at to get that arc.

I have looked here,
[How do I calculate the height of an arc?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773648/how-do-i-calculate-the-height-of-an-arc)

[radius = distance? arc length = height?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320944/radius-distance-arc-length-height)

and I have read various things on calculating the Sagitta, like from here:

https://www.mathopenref.com/sagitta.html

This one *might* be what I need?  I admit I didn't understand how to do the math.

[In a circle, is there a formula for the length of the sagitta if the chord length and arc length are known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845001/in-a-circle-is-there-a-formula-for-the-length-of-the-sagitta-if-the-chord-lengt)

Comment: What is your ideal height for the hoop house?

Comment: [This](https://handymath.com/cgi-bin/arc18.cgi) tool may be of help to you.

Comment: @an4s I picked 7' but it should probably be about 8-10. Thanks for the tool.  Edit:  500 Internal Error.  Will try again later.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed part of the URL. Try this: http://www.handymath.com/cgi-bin/arc18.cgi?submit=Entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hoop house is to be  $14$ feet wide and   $7$ feet high at the center then it will be a semicircle.  Your PVC must be as long as half the circumference of a circle of radius $7$, so
$$
7\pi \approx 22 \text{ feet}.
$$

Edit: For an arbitrary height of more than $7$ feet you can't have a circular arc.

Comment: I knew it had to be so simple I was overlooking the obvious.  Thanks!